Rocky Linux 9, Mailscanner - Postfix issue, Unable to kick message
Aug 29 20:19:06 kratos MailScanner[128919]: New Batch: Scanning 1 messages, 1557 bytes
Aug 29 20:19:06 kratos MailScanner[128919]: Virus and Content Scanning: Starting
Aug 29 20:19:06 kratos MailScanner[128919]: SpamAssassin cache hit for message B1EBE808CF74.ABB4C
Aug 29 20:19:07 kratos MailScanner[128919]: Requeue: B1EBE808CF74.ABB4C to B1EBE808CF74.ABB4C
Aug 29 20:19:07 kratos postfix/qmqpd[130594]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 29 20:19:07 kratos postfix/qmqpd[130594]: match_list_match: localhost: no match
Aug 29 20:19:07 kratos postfix/qmqpd[130594]: match_list_match: 127.0.0.1: no match
Aug 29 20:19:07 kratos postfix/qmqpd[130594]: netstring_put: write netstring len 66 data DError: localhost[127.0.0.1] i
Aug 29 20:19:08 kratos postfix/qmqpd[130594]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 14 flush 70
Aug 29 20:19:08 kratos postfix/qmqpd[130594]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 29 20:19:08 kratos MailScanner[128919]: Unable to kick message /var/spool/MailScanner/milterout/B1EBE808CF74.ABB4C, rejected by local relay, quarantining message
Aug 29 20:19:08 kratos MailScanner[128919]: Uninfected: Delivered 1 messages
Aug 29 20:19:08 kratos MailScanner[128919]: Deleted 1 messages from processing-database
I found all the messages located in /var/spool/MailScanner/milterin so none of the messages are getting processed and delivered but what did it mess up? Also what can I do to reprocess all these messages?
